# Restangular with infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, restangular

I have a Restangular collection and it works great:

```
$scope.threads = Restangular.all('thread').getList({ limit: 10, offset: 0 }).$object;
```

But I'd like to be able load more thread models when the user initiates it either by scrolling to the bottom of the list or by clicking a 'Load more' button. If I call .getList() again with a new offset it just replaces the whole collection:

```
$scope.threads.getList({ limit: 10, offset: 10 });
```

Is there a way to have the returned models added or pushed onto the existing array instead of replacing them?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Promises that Restangular supports and when the data comes back use Array.push() to append the results to $scope.threads

Something like this:

```
$scope.threads = Restangular.all('thread').getList({ limit: 10, offset: 0 }).then(function(resultThreads){
$scope.threads.push(resultThreads);
});
```

You'd need to keep track of your offset so you get the next set each time you either scroll or click 'Load more'.
It improve performance, if you are dealing with a huge amount of data you may want to think about removing items from the begining of the array while appending to the end.

[Angular Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

[Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#differences-with-resource)